# Find data within specific dates?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm learning database, and i have 2 questions: 
How can I find out the how many Employees visited the shop in January 2010?

Table is as follows:

```
X:Employees(PK),VisitDate, EmployeeNumber(FK)
Y:EmployeeNumber 
SELECT * FROM `X` WHERE `VisitDate ` BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2010-01-31'
```

This just shows the data of people who visited between certain month, is it possible to find out the total amount of people?

Second Question is:

How can I use JOINS to show the EmployeeNumber as well as how many employees visited the shop in January 2010?

Comment: 1. `COUNT(*)`. 2. It's not clear 3. Your condition doesn't include the whole January 31st, but only its midnight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the number of people visiting in January, you just need to modify your SQL as follows.

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
    SELECT EmployeeNumber, COUNT(1) AS TotalAmountOfVisitor 
    FROM X 
    WHERE VisitDate BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2010-01-31 23:59:59'
    GROUP BY EmployeeNumber
) AS RefTable
INNER JOIN Y ON RefTable.EmployeeNumber = Y.EmployeeNumber
```

Thanks @zerkms for correcting.

Comment: `'2010-01-31 23:59:59'`

Comment: Or you can have `MONTH(VisitDate) = 1 AND YEAR(VisitDate) = 2010` to extract only January 2010 info.

Comment: it will cause a full table scan (unless you have a function based indexes, which aren't supported in mysql). So not recommended to use in real life

Comment: EmployeeNumber in Y table is a unique number(PK) which connects to table X (I forgot to add EmployeeNumber(FK) in table X)

Comment: If so, what I will do is first extract out the number of visits based on employee number using `GROUP BY`. After that, I just do an `INNER JOIN` between the results and Y table. I have updated my answer accordingly. Still, I think the need of having the Y table is a bit strange. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1)SELECT count(*) FROM `X` WHERE `VisitDate` BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2010-01-31'

2) You cannot do that.